# S3 Bash Script looping

Tags: bash, shell, s3cmd

I've written a script to get the size of my S3 storage, the script works fine barring the fact that it keeps looping and never ends. I get all the outputs as I need but it keeps going through them.

Any ideas on why its looping?

```
#!/bin/sh
DAY=$(date +"%d%b%Y")
BUCKET='/home/user/Scripts/Holding/s3buckets.txt'
BLIST='/home/user/Scripts/Holding/blist.txt'
LOGDIR='/home/user/Scripts/Holding/'
USAGE=$BLIST
s3cmd ls > $BUCKET
awk '{print $3}' $BUCKET > $BLIST 
while read USAGE; do
s3cmd du -H $USAGE
done < $BUCKET > $LOGDIR/S3Usage$DAY.txt
```

Comment: Whats the format of `s3cmd ls` output?

Comment: `2011-01-28 15:24  s3://bucket1
2010-12-24 10:51  s3://bucket2`

Comment: Why do you have `USAGE=$BLIST` when you're going to clobber it with the `while read ... < $BUCKET`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change `s3cmd du -H $USAGE` to `s3cmd du -H s3://$USAGE`**

Without the `s3://`, s3cmd defaults to giving the listing for all buckets.  I'm betting that `s3buckets.txt` just has the bucket names, not the protocol prefix.

Comment: the s3bucklist.txt is the list of s3 and then the blist.txt cuts them into a list of the correct prefix so not sure if that is the reason

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  The problem is that you're doing all that to prep `$BLIST` but then ignoring it and reading from `$BUCKET`.